# Angular tree grid with buffering feature

Tags: angular, plugins, grid, record

I am using `angular 7` and looking for a tree grid plugin with a buffering feature while loading a large number of records. So that we can load only visible part of the record.  While scrolling down it loads remaining records.  Is there any plugin in angular with this feature?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you try angular virtual scroll  https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: Are you talking about this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-virtual-scroller

Answer (score 2):

Can you please elaborate, however if you looking for infinite data to be displayed try this. By using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport which is a new feature of angular 7

```js
export class AppComponent {
  numbers: number[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10000; index++) {
      this.numbers.push(index);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center">Virtual Scroll using Angular 7</h1>

<ul class="list">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport  style="height: 500px" itemSize="90" >
    <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let n of numbers">
      <li class="list-item"> {{n}} </li>
    </ng-container>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ul>
```

Please refer :

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-use-virtual-scrolling-using-angular-7-cdk-9802110111fa